# Using jQuery and Chrome devtools to get all the text elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Chrome console and want to get all the text elements using jQuery.

How can I do that, like extracting all the .pdf links below?

```
var links = [];
$('.className').each(function(){ links.push( $(this).attr('href') ) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = []; 
$('.className').each(function(){ 
  links.push( $(this).prop('href') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
$("a[href$='.pdf'],a[href$='.PDF']").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('href') });
```

TL;DR answer:

There are a couple of ways to do this. To get all the hrefs, it's sufficient to do what you did initially. Here it is, cleaned up slightly as a map rather than explicit loop:

```
var hrefs = $("a").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('href') });
```

Here I select `a` elements, but you could change that to `a.className` or `.className` if you like.

To find all the links that lead to PDFs is fundamentally hard. You'd have to take all the hrefs, retrieve the content, and determine if the links lead to PDFs. Technically you'd have to do this even if the links don't suggest they lead to PDFs. Indeed, even if they appear to lead to HTML, PNG, or other non-PDF content.

But usually you'd be happy to find links that end in `".pdf"`, right? That's an easier starting place. For this, use the `$=` operator in a CSS selector:

```
var pdf_hrefs = $("a[href$='.pdf']").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('href') });
```

The problem is, `$=` is case-sensitive. It will catch `.pdf` but not `.PDF` extensions. It might be fine for some sites, but uppercase file names appear pretty often in practice. To fix this, use alternation:

```
var pdf_hrefs2 = $("a[href$='.pdf'],a[href$='.PDF']").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('href') });
```

Now you're catching `.pdf` and `.PDF`. This is good enough 98% of the time.

But if you really want to catch those `.pdF`,
`.pDf`, `.pDF`, `.Pdf`, `.PdF`, and `.PDf` jokers, then you need to check all hrefs, but filter out those that are some version of PDF:

```
// convenient string test function
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

var pdf_hrefs3 = $("a").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('href')})
                       .toArray()
                       .filter(function(x) { return x.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"); });
```

[Here's a sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathaneunice/c0j69dsy/) that runs all these options live. Watch the console for the key output.